# flutter `windows.locales` return different value when app start between `debug & running` and `directly running`

Tags: flutter, locale

I was check the value of `window.locals` in different time of app running:

> 1. App start.
> 2. `window.onLocaleChanged()` get called.
> 3. User interact.

### Steps to Reproduce

#### code:

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:ui';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => MyAppState();
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  var text = "empty";
  var textStreamController = StreamController<String>();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    textStreamController.close();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    var localList = window.locales;      //<-----   this after: app start
    print(localList);

    text = 'Flutter Demo Home Page:${localList ?? "null"}';
    textStreamController.sink.add(text);

    window.onLocaleChanged = () {
      localList = window.locales;         //<-----   this after: onLocaleChanged
      text = 'Flutter Demo Home Page(New):${localList ?? "null"}';
      textStreamController.sink.add(text);
    };
  }

  void onClick() {
    var localList = window.locales;        //<-----   this after: user interact
    text = 'Flutter Demo Home Page(Click):${localList ?? "null"}';
    textStreamController.sink.add(text);
    showToast(localList ?? 'null');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Material(
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(text),
              StreamBuilder(
                stream: textStreamController.stream,
                builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
                  return Text(
                    '${snapshot.data}',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.green),
                  );
                },
              ),
              FlatButton(
                onPressed: onClick,
                color: Colors.blue,
                child: Text('Click'),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

#### The result when app `debug & running`:

[image][image]

#### The result when `app stop debug & running`

[image][image]

### Is this as expected as design ?

> - The locals don't have initial value when `directly run` ?
> - The locals have initial value when `debugging` ?